# Do I need a TOKEN and a VERIFIER in my cookie for a 'Remember Me' function?

Tags: php

I am creating a 'remember me' function. I have tried to read many different documents and manuals to ensure that it is as secure as possible.

As you can see, I am creating a $token which when verifying the cookie, we lookup in the MySQL database and find the user ID to log them in.

I just read another article which suggests that I should be storing a RANDOM token and also a VERIFIER that is SHA(384) into the cookie and then use both to look them up in the MySQL database.

I can't see how that becomes any more secure than the implementation below, as if they somehow have the token, they would also have the verifier as well?

```
if ($remember == 1) { 
    $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
    // insert token into the mysql database
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tokens (token, userid) VALUES(:token, :userid)");
    $stmt->execute(array( 
        'token' => $token,
        'userid' => $rRow->ID
    ));
    setcookie ("MCTOKEN", $token, time() + 2419200,'/', SITE_DOMAIN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the situation that user's cookies are being sniffed/stolen: the bad guy will instantly gain access to user's account just by creating mctoken, with sniffed value, in his browser.

You need somehow to secure this situation. And here comes the verification value. It will be a string with data that you can reproduce next time. The simplest example is going with user agent + salt. You can think of something else.

In this case even if you have both token + verifier, but verification value doesn't match current environment you are secure and user won't be logged in!

Answer (score 0):

You could store both inside your cookie and if the verifier is somehow unique (maybe verifying the user agent or IP address or so), then even if someone is successful in stealing the token, his environment might not match the verification. However, it would be a good idea to have a verifier on server-side as well, which would verify something different than the one in the cookie. The added security would be that this part could not be stolen.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses, I think I understand now ... my updated code below ... obviously when I verify I'll need to use the same salt along with the 'current' user agent to see if they match ...

```
if ($remember == 1) { 

            $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(18));
            $salt = '#$RaNdSa48Lf:f';
            $series = hash('sha256', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . $salt);

            $expire = time() + 314496000;

            // insert token and series into the database
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tokens (series, token, userid, expire) VALUES(:series, :token, :userid, :expire)");
            $stmt->execute(array( 
                        'series'    => $series,
                        'token'     => $token,
                        'userid'    => $rRow->ID,
                        'expire'    => $expire 
                ));

            setcookie ("MCTOKEN", $token .':'. $series, $expire, '/', SITE_DOMAIN);

        }
```

Comment: `series` in your new implementation does not add any value from security perspective.